# How to split an string array element by whitespace, and forming two new arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I searched for **"How to split a String"** related questions, they all seem to be something like `String.split("")`, and you end up having a `String` array with each part being its element. But I didn't mean that, my question is:

I have an array of String called columnNameType:

```
columnNameType = {TeamName string, City string, Sport string, Year int}
```

each element in this array contains columnName and its corresponding type, for instance:
TeamName string: the columnName is TeamName, its type is string.

But I want to get two new arrays respectively containing columnNname and columnType:

```
types = {string, string, string, int}
names = {TeamName, City, Sport, Year}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Show your code. A vague description of code is very difficult to work with.

Comment: what is `types` and `names` ??

Comment: `columnNameType[i].split(" ")` results in the array `{"type", "name"}`. Grab the first element and save it in `types[i]` and grab the second element and save it in `names[i]`.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve might be considered an antipattern and you might look for alternatives. For additional info refer to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_array and https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned the split-function can handle this.

```
String[] types = new String[columnNameType.length];
String[] names = new String[columnNameType.length];

for(int i = 0 ; i< columnNameType.length; ++i){
   names[i] = columnNameType[i].split(" ")[0];
   types[i] = columnNameType[i].split(" ")[1];
}
```

iterate your array and split every element on its own.

Comment: yes i think it works,it's just names[i] =  columnNameType[i].split(" ")[0], while types[i] = columnNameType[i].split(" ")[1];